# mysql, what exactly that code "constraint" does?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I know what foreign key is. However what is the difference between adding the

CONSTRAINT `test1`    ??

AND

without it?

The code "CONSTRAINT" what exactly does it do, since you can add foreign key without that code anyway.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: `CONSTRAINT` is an optional keyword that's part of the standard SQL syntax. Other databases allow you to create other kinds of constraints, but MySQL only has foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just RTM:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Check this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fb10

```
create table a (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

create table b (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                a_id int,

    CONSTRAINT a_id  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)  )ENGINE=INNODB ;

create table c (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                a_id int,
    CONSTRAINT a_id_C  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)  )ENGINE=INNODB ;

    #CONSTRAINT a_id  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)  )ENGINE=INNODB ;

create table d (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                a_id int,

    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)  )ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

The idea of `CONSTRAINT` is to create unique name against whole database.
So if you ever created `CONSTRAINT a_id` index, database will check and refuse any attempt to create an index with the same name on any other table.

In example above If you will try to uncomment

```
#CONSTRAINT a_id  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
```

for `c` table, mysql server will alert an error message, because `a_id` was already used for `b` table.

And at the same time if you just don't use `CONSTRAINT` you can create index with the same name as it shown for table `d`.